# How Would I Make This Animation?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

So I've got this idea. Basically, I want a circle div in the center. And I want a bunch of little lines coming off the div, kind of like rays of light coming off the Sun (that's supposed to be what it represents). How would I do that? Would I use JavaScript or CSS3 Animations?

I could probably do it right now, but it would get incredibly laggy after a couple minutes, because the lines wouldn't delete themselves after they left the page. I don't really know how to do that. Also, it just wouldn't look very good, because I have a feeling my methods would be pretty primitive.

The tricky bit is that most of the lines will be travelling at an angle of some form (because rays of light come off at all 360 degrees of the sun), meaning I'd have to set the margin-top and the margin-left or margin-right at the same time in some way that makes them go strait in exactly the direction that I want... This is probably a pretty complicated animation to do, isn't it...

Anyone know of some tutorials to point me to that would help with this? I hope this made sense...

Comment: This is a nice guide for SVG animations: http://css-tricks.com/guide-svg-animations-smil/

Answer (score 1):

Below is the code of the basic HTML document with `embedded styling and JQuery`. Make sure you maximize your browser window to see the animation.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#sun
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -200px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    background: yellow;
    border-radius: 200px;
    background-image: -moz-radial-gradient(45px 45px 60deg, circle cover, yellow 0%, orange 100%, red 95%);
    background-image: -webkit-radial-gradient(45px 45px, circle cover, yellow, orange);
    background-image: radial-gradient(45px 45px 60deg, circle cover, yellow 0%, orange 100%, red 95%);
}
.ray
{
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: orange;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -15px;
}
#one { transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(215px); }
#two { transform: rotate(-90deg)  translate(215px); }
#three { transform: rotate(-135deg) translate(215px); }
#four { transform: rotate(-180deg) translate(215px); }
#five { transform: rotate(-225deg) translate(215px); }
#six { transform: rotate(-270deg) translate(215px); }
#seven { transform: rotate(-315deg) translate(215px); }
#eight { transform: rotate(-360deg) translate(215px); }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sun"></div>
    <div id="one" class="ray"></div>
    <div id="two" class="ray"></div>
    <div id="three" class="ray"></div>
    <div id="four" class="ray"></div>
    <div id="five" class="ray"></div>
    <div id="six" class="ray"></div>
    <div id="seven" class="ray"></div>
    <div id="eight" class="ray"></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function movement() {
$("#two").animate({top: '-=50'}, 300);
$("#three").animate({top: '-=35.35', left: '-=35.35'}, 300);
$("#four").animate({left: '-=50'}, 300);
$("#five").animate({top: '+=35.35', left: '-=35.35'}, 300);
$("#six").animate({top: '+=50'}, 300);
$("#seven").animate({top: '+=35.35', left: '+=35.35'}, 300);
$("#eight").animate({left: '+=50'}, 300);
$("#one").animate({top: '-=35.35', left: '+=35.35'}, 300);
//Reverse Animation
$("#two").animate({top: '+=50'}, 450);
$("#three").animate({top: '+=35.35', left: '+=35.35'}, 450);
$("#four").animate({left: '+=50'}, 450);
$("#five").animate({top: '-=35.35', left: '+=35.35'}, 450);
$("#six").animate({top: '-=50'}, 450);
$("#seven").animate({top: '-=35.35', left: '-=35.35'}, 450);
$("#eight").animate({left: '-=50'}, 450);
$("#one").animate({top: '+=35.35', left: '-=35.35'}, 450);
setTimeout(movement, 750);
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    movement();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Wow... Very well done. Thank you for actually answering the question (although I must also give credit to Joseph. That link was helpful as well). This isn't very complicated, and I probably could have done it myself. But you forgot that I want the divs to move away from the sun in all 360 directions. Not in strait lines, but like you'd expect rays to move from a circular Sun. How would I do that?

Comment: Tommay - Can you be a little more specific please? What do you mean moving away from the sun in all 360 directions (degrees*)? Do you mean that you want the divs to move across the circle - such as traveling across the 360 degrees of the sun? I would love to help. Thanks.

Comment: Erm... Like this: http://ak2.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/20958/preview/stock-footage-lens-flare-animated-rotating-glow-light-rings-and-rays-red-to-orange-quicktime-seamless-loop.jpg
See how the rays are moving away at the angle they should be? Instead of only going north, south, east and west, they go north-east, south-east, etc.